# how to get this linear regression model more accurate as i am getting accuracy such as 5% which is not at all viable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

so the dataset i am using is of 100k rows and 22 columns and i am trying to predict housing and real estate prices using this dataset. but the accuracy i am getting is 5% . i wanted to know what is it that i am doing it incorrectly which makes my model irrelevant.

i have tried handling null values. also deleted some columns which were irrelevant and made the whole data non-null and then prerformed linear regression.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

data= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\nachi\Downloads\nyc-rolling-sales.csv')
data.head()




data.isnull().sum()

data.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1,inplace=True)
data.drop('EASE-MENT',axis=1,inplace=True)

data['SALE PRICE'] = pd.to_numeric(data['SALE PRICE'], errors='coerce')
data['YEAR BUILT'] = pd.to_numeric(data['YEAR BUILT'], errors='coerce')

data['LAND SQUARE FEET']=data['LAND SQUARE FEET'].replace(np.NaN , data['LAND SQUARE FEET'].mean())

data.isnull().sum()

data['GROSS SQUARE FEET']=data['GROSS SQUARE FEET'].replace(np.NaN , data['GROSS SQUARE FEET'].mean())

data.drop('SALE DATE',axis=1,inplace=True)

data['SALE PRICE']=data['SALE PRICE'].replace(np.NaN , data['SALE PRICE'].mean())

data.isnull().sum()
```

output-
BOROUGH                           0
NEIGHBORHOOD                      0
BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY           0
TAX CLASS AT PRESENT              0
BLOCK                             0
LOT                               0
BUILDING CLASS AT PRESENT         0
ADDRESS                           0
APARTMENT NUMBER                  0
ZIP CODE                          0
RESIDENTIAL UNITS                 0
COMMERCIAL UNITS                  0
TOTAL UNITS                       0
LAND SQUARE FEET                  0
GROSS SQUARE FEET                 0
YEAR BUILT                        0
TAX CLASS AT TIME OF SALE         0
BUILDING CLASS AT TIME OF SALE    0
SALE PRICE                        0
dtype: int64

### now there is no null values so i started fitting the model

```
cols=('TOTAL UNITS','LAND SQUARE FEET','GROSS SQUARE FEET','TAX CLASS AT TIME OF SALE','TAX CLASS AT PRESENT','BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY','BUILDING CLASS AT PRESENT','BUILDING CLASS AT TIME OF SALE')
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
for c in cols:
lbl = LabelEncoder() 
lbl.fit(list(data[c].values)) 
data[c] = lbl.transform(list(data[c].values))


y = data['SALE PRICE']
X = data[['TOTAL UNITS','LAND SQUARE FEET','GROSS SQUARE FEET','TAX CLASS AT TIME OF SALE','TAX CLASS AT PRESENT','BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY','BUILDING CLASS AT PRESENT','BUILDING CLASS AT TIME OF SALE']]


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1001)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()

lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

print('Coefficients: \n', lm.coef_)
```

output-Coefficients: 
 [ 1.77645664e+05  2.94873434e+02  1.54407602e+02  4.57057732e+06
 -4.83785607e+05 -2.64722070e+05  1.84561247e+04 -1.80610896e+03]

```
predictions = lm.predict( X_test)

from sklearn import metrics
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions))
print('MSE:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions))
print('RMSE:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)))
```

output-MAE: 1278736.556862968
MSE: 35124542426665.445
RMSE: 5926596.192306799

```
accuracy = lm.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy*100,'%')
```

output-5.098736520495494 %

> Blockquote

Comment: Please notice that accuracy is neither an appropriate performance measure for linear regression nor it is what is returned by `lm.score()`; the latter returns the coefficient of determination R^2, so your computed "accuracy" is actually 0.05, and *not* 5%. Before start assuming things, your first step should always be to [check the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score).

Answer (score -1):

lm.score() returns the coefficient of determination R^2,

you can use metrics.accuracy_score to get accuracy : [metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)

Before start assuming things, your first step should always be to [check the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score)

Comment: yes agree, and you could try other https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html linear models as well, and try to just run it over one or two weights instead of all weights.For example LAND SQUARE FEET','GROSS SQUARE FEET'

Comment: An advice that accuracy is just meaningless in regression settings (as in OP's case), along with that `lm.score()` computes something different, was expected as a minimum meaningful answer here.